# POI evaluate formulas

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have tried following code, to hard coded evaluate the cells were the function is inside but I get following error: **java.lang.RuntimeException: resource 'functionMetadata.txt' not found**

This is an example of the function in my Excel cell: **=COUNTIFS(Reporting!$H$2:$H$65536;"In time";Reporting!$S$2:$S$65536;"HYPER")**

```
         HSSFFormulaEvaluator fe = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(wb);
         CellValue cv = null;
         HSSFCell cell = null;
         //Hyper refresh
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(6).getCell(1); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(7).getCell(1); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(8).getCell(1); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);

             //Express refresh
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(6).getCell(7); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(7).getCell(7); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(8).getCell(7); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);

         //MarketI refresh
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(32).getCell(1); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(33).getCell(1); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(34).getCell(1); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);

         //MarketF refresh
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(32).getCell(7); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(33).getCell(7); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
         cell = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(34).getCell(7); 
         cv = fe.evaluate(cell);
```

Comment: Looks like your `poi-x.y.jar` is broken or you somehow unpacked/repackaged it? The file should be in there.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51534

Comment: Any idea how I can add the txt file to the poi.jar?

Comment: You don't need to add it, you need to make sure you're using the latest version of POI + don't have any broken/old versions on your classpath